# Jquery Function, Not quite right

Tags: jquery, function, refresh, element

Just need a couple of pointers on how I've "messed up" calling my function. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var update = function(element, url) {
$('element').fadeOut('slow', function() {
$('element').load('url');
$('element').fadeIn('slow'); });
}

var refresh_div = setInterval(function() {
update(".element-one", "../logs/url-one.txt");
update(".element-two", "../logs/url-two.txt");
}, 5000);

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

});
```

So you can see I have a function (probably faulty) that simply fades out, loads then fades in.
Next, I am trying to call the function within my `setInterval` function, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element` and `url` are variables holding the values, not strings so use them as such

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var update = function (element, url) {
        $(element).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(element).load(url);
            $(element).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }

    var refresh_div = setInterval(function () {
        update(".element-one", "../logs/url-one.txt");
        update(".element-two", "../logs/url-two.txt");
    }, 5000);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow how simple was that!? Thanks.
A very important lesson learned here - tiny mistakes can sometimes catch you out!